# best strategy for backing up *your* scripts in /usr/local/bin?

Tags: scripting, backup

So I've started writing a few scripts. Following advice on the internet ([1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/465109/where-should-i-put-my-script-so-that-i-can-run-it-by-a-direct-command),[2](https://superuser.com/questions/185184/where-should-i-put-my-script)), the best recommended and most straightforward location for them is in `/usr/local/bin`.

However, on my Ubuntu 16.04LTS system, there's quite a lot in there as it is, e.g. Dropbox, dnsmasq, libreoffice, firefox, etc.

I am thinking about making a script to automate backups. It struck me that filtering out *my* custom scripts from the machine-written ones would be quite a challenge.

I suppose there might be file attributes that could be used as a filter - I don't know, are there? e.g. created by . Or maybe a subdirectory works in there, e.g. `/usr/local/bin/custom_scripts`?

What is your strategy?

(All my searches on this question keep filling up with scripts *for* backups. Noise >> signal)

Cheers -

Comment: I would have a development machine and deploy them to other servers.

Comment: I usually stash _my_ scripts in `$HOME/bin`, which I add to my path.  I sync that to a private git repository for easy installation on other hosts.  But this is a cat with many skins, and if you ask ten people how to do this, you'll get fifteen equally viable answers.

Answer (score 2):

`/usr/local/bin` is the place for executable scripts and binaries to be stored, not the place for source files. So keep the scripts unter `~/src` somewhere (ideally even under version control) and use a build script/make file to "deploy" (or just copy) them into `/usr/local/bin` after a change. This build script can also ensure that all scripts are installed with the executable bit set and do some basic sanity checks.

Backup of your scripts will then be included in your standard backup of `~`.